# DJango getting static bootstrap stylesheet to apply in view

Tags: css, django, django-staticfiles

I am scratching my head on this because none of this is making sense.

I am running a Django project in dev mode.

I have a base.html that I include in many of my pages.

Here is my file structure:

[image: django file structure]

Here is the simple base.html code:

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <!-- Required meta tags -->
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, shrink-to-fit=no">

  <!-- Bootstrap CSS-->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-ggOyR0iXCbMQv3Xipma34MD+dH/1fQ784/j6cY/iJTQUOhcWr7x9JvoRxT2MZw1T" crossorigin="anonymous">


  <title>RAHQ Locations {% block head_title %} {% endblock %}</title>
</head>

<body style="background-color: #26272b; color: #fff">
  {% include 'navbar.html' %}
  <div class='container-fluid'>
    {% block content %}

    {% endblock %}
  </div>
  {% include 'js.html' %}

  <br>
  <br>
  {% include 'footer.html' %}
</body>

</html>
```

Everything is working PERFECT like this.  But I want to make changes to the bootstrap css, so I download the bootstrap css file, rename it to styles.css, and place it in my static folder.

so I replace the bootstrap href with everything I can to access my static styles.css

I follow all the online guides that tell me to tweak my settings.py and url.py to allow the use of static files.

I have tried bringing in the path from the view.py:

```
url = staticfiles_storage.path('styles.css')
```

I have tried even hand typing the entire path into the href (C:/Try-Django-2.2-master/src/static/styles.css)

I have tried virtually anything you can think of, and I can't get the styles to load.  What am I doing wrong!?

If I put the actual path to the CSS file in my browser, I can see all the CSS... so I am at a loss here:

C:/Try-Django-2.2-master/src/static/styles.css

Here is my settings.py:

```
import os

BASE_DIR = os.path.dirname(os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath(__file__)))
DEBUG = True
ALLOWED_HOSTS = ['54.245.181.209', '*']
LOGIN_URL = '/login'

INSTALLED_APPS = [ # components
    'django.contrib.admin',
    'django.contrib.auth',
    'django.contrib.contenttypes',
    'django.contrib.sessions',
    'django.contrib.messages',
    'django.contrib.staticfiles',
    'locationSearch',

]

MIDDLEWARE = [
    'django.middleware.security.SecurityMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.sessions.middleware.SessionMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.csrf.CsrfViewMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.auth.middleware.AuthenticationMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.messages.middleware.MessageMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.clickjacking.XFrameOptionsMiddleware',
]

ROOT_URLCONF = 'try_django.urls'

TEMPLATES = [
    {
        'BACKEND': 'django.template.backends.django.DjangoTemplates',
        'DIRS': [os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'templates')],
        'APP_DIRS': True,
        'OPTIONS': {
            'context_processors': [
                'django.template.context_processors.debug',
                'django.template.context_processors.request',
                'django.contrib.auth.context_processors.auth',
                'django.contrib.messages.context_processors.messages',
            ],
        },
    },
]

WSGI_APPLICATION = 'try_django.wsgi.application'


DATABASES = {
    'default': {
        'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.sqlite3',
        'NAME': os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'db.sqlite3'),
    }
}

AUTH_PASSWORD_VALIDATORS = [
    {
        'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.UserAttributeSimilarityValidator',
    },
    {
        'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.MinimumLengthValidator',
    },
    {
        'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.CommonPasswordValidator',
    },
    {
        'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.NumericPasswordValidator',
    },
]

LANGUAGE_CODE = 'en-us'

TIME_ZONE = 'UTC'

USE_I18N = True

USE_L10N = True

USE_TZ = True

STATIC_ROOT = os.path.join(os.path.dirname(BASE_DIR), 'src/static')
STATIC_URL = 'src/static/'

STATICFILES_DIRS = [
    os.path.join(BASE_DIR, "src/static"),
]

MEDIA_ROOT = os.path.join(os.path.dirname(BASE_DIR), 'src/media')
MEDIA_URL = 'src/media/'  # django-storages
```

Comment: show your settings for static files and urls.py too.

Comment: I added the settings.py.  Let me know if you see anything weird

Comment: Did you do: `python manage.py collectstatic`

Comment: This opened up a completely new can of worms and sent me down a wormhole and I have no idea what is wrong here.

I even started a completely new project with a new application and I am running into the same problem.

Comment: Does collectstatic matter if this is just a development project?

Answer (score 0):

You need to make some changes on your code.

Please consider changing your settings.py and then change your href link for CSS.

Here we go...

#### settings.py

```
STATICFILES_DIRS = [
    os.path.join(BASE_DIR,'src'),
]
```

The link for your CSS should be something like this:

#### base template link

```
<link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="{% static 'css/main.css' %}" media="screen,projection" />
```

Hope that works for you!

Comment: So take a look at my settings.py I just added.  I already had the os.path join.

Also, the baste template link that you posted doesn't have the same path or stylesheet name, do you want me to rename it and change the path?